# Create index for a group of data in R

Tags: r

I need to create an index (0 or 1) over some data in R. This is my data:

```
E1<- c("A1","A2","A3","A4")
E2 <- c("2","0","12","8")
data<-data.frame(E1,E2)
```

A1,A2,A3 and A4 are the roles in a company and E2 contains how many employees we have for each role. So, for having more employees with A1 and A2 roles, the index needs to be 0, and if the opposite the index needs to be 1. In this case, the index should be 1, because we have more employees with A3 and A4 roles.

Comment: please explain the logic more completely or provide an expected output

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want:

- index = 0, when E1 = A1 or E1 = A2;
- index = 1, when E1 = A3 or E1 = A4.

If so, a solution would be:

### Data

```
E1 <- c("A1","A2","A3","A4")
E2 <- c(2,0,12,8)
data <-data.frame(E1,E2)
```

### Code

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  mutate(index = if_else(E1 %in% c("A1","A2"),0,1))
```

### Output

```
  E1 E2 index
1 A1  2     0
2 A2  0     0
3 A3 12     1
4 A4  8     1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
E1 <- c("A1", "A2", "A3", "A4")
E2 <- c("2", "0", "12", "8")
data <- data.frame(E1, E2)

data$grp <- ifelse(data$E1 %in% c(
  "A1",
  "A2"
), 1, 2)

(grp_sums <- split(data, ~grp) |> lapply(\(x)sum(as.integer(x$E2))))

grp_index_choice <- if (grp_sums$`1` > grp_sums$`2`) {
  c(1, 0)
} else {
  0:1
}

(fin <- merge(
  data,
  data.frame(
    grp = 1:2,
    index = grp_index_choice
  )
))

fin_no_grp <- fin
fin_no_grp$grp <- NULL
fin_no_grp
```